# Strip Month and Year from file name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

This is my dataset look like so guys can you help me to create 2 new column(i.e., month and year) that takes month and year from the file name and like this there are lots of files containing all the month so please help me fetch all the month and year from filename and insert it to new column.

Comment: filename is a string so you could slice year - `text[-9:-5]`. As for month you can `split(" ")` text to list of words and then get element with index `[-2]`

Comment: but you only seen the one files there are so many files that has different structure like "102 RB loss Chamdor June 2018.xlsx". @furas

Comment: year is always in the same place - `[-9:-5]` - it counts chars from the end of string.

Comment: Please no images of code or data. And please think about what is meant by a [mcve]. Perhaps you consider putting at least the effort in making a good question as you expect to be put in the answers. E.g.: Don't get me wrong, nobody here expects perfect English - but would it be possible to at least use some punctuation to form and separate several sentences instead of this monotonic stream of words...?

Comment: Thanks for a great suggestion @SpghttCd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Year is always in the same place - `[-9:-5]` - it counts chars from the end of string.

If you split filename using `" "` then you get list and month will have index `-2`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'filename':[
        "102 RB loss Chamdor June 2018.xlsx",
        "102 RB loss Chamdor Januray 2018.xlsx",
    ]})

df['year'] = df['filename'].str[-9:-5]
df['month'] = df['filename'].apply(lambda x:x.split(" ")[-2])

print(df)
```

Result

```
                                filename  year    month
0     102 RB loss Chamdor June 2018.xlsx  2018     June
1  102 RB loss Chamdor Januray 2018.xlsx  2018  Januray
```

---

**EDIT:** as said @SpghttCd instead `apply()` you can use

```
df['month'] = df['filename'].str.split().str[-2]
```

---

If you have more complex names then you can try regex

```
df['year'] = df['filename'].str.extract('(\d{4})')
df['month'] = df['filename'].str.extract('(June|Januray|names|of|other|months)')
```

Comment: IMO an improvement would be to avoid `apply` also for the month extraction: `df['filename'].str.split().str[-2]`

Comment: @SpghttCd - thank you, I tried `df['filename'].str.split()[-2]` which doesn't work - so I missed second `.str`

Comment: Just timed the two versions and saw that it is _not_ an improvement. Probably because you have the indexing `[-2]` already included in your lambda, `apply` is here faster.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list where all month names are represented and use find function to strip out the month name.
To get the year use @furas method.